# find out whether focus change was done with tab or mouse click in Swing

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a FocusListener to select all the text in a JTextField when this JTextField gets the focus:

```
final FocusListener fl= new FocusAdapter() {
 @Override
 public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    final JTextField tf= (JTextField) e.getComponent();
    tf.selectAll();
  }

  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    final JTextField tf= (JTextField) e.getComponent();
    tf.select(-1, -1);
  }
}
```

However, I want that this only happens if the user switches the focus with the tab key. It should not happen if the user clicks on the new component. But the FocusEvent doesn't provide such information. 
Is there a way to distinguish these cases?

Comment: May be you can use getOppositeComponent() method of the FocusEvent?

Comment: @StanislavL How that? There is always an opposite component, regardless of using the tab key or the mouse (or even doing it programmatically)

Comment: you can tab from particular componnet (previous one) if it's another component that's not TAB

Comment: @StanislavL That's not reliable. I the opposite component is the "previous one" I still cannot differentiate. And even then this seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but what happens if you attach a `MouseListener` to it as well. If you get the `MouseEvent` right before you get the `FocusEvent`, you can let the `MouseEvent` update a flag and ignore the `FocusEvent` if that flag is set

Comment: @Robin I thought about something like that. But it is also just a hack and not a reliable way to detect the difference.

Answer (score -1):

This do the job for one **JTextField**(you can tranform it for more)(it's not good way) but it works...
I made a **window(frame)** and add two **JTextFields (field 1,field 2)**
I use the Focuslistener you have had given(no exactly).
I use a ***flag*** to keep it work.
Let me know if your job is done with this....

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class cl  implements MouseListener{ 

  private boolean flag=false;

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);

public cl(){ //Constructor

    frame.setSize(100,350);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());



    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(field2);


    frame.setVisible(true);

    field.addMouseListener(this); //add MouseListene to JTextField field.       

    field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
          if(flag==true){ //if flag=true;
            final JTextField tf= (JTextField) e.getComponent();
            tf.selectAll();
            flag=false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(flag==false){  //if flag=false;
             final JTextField tf= (JTextField) e.getComponent();
                tf.select(-1, -1);
             flag=true;}

        }

    });
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new cl();
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    flag=false;

}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    flag=false;

}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    flag=false;

}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    flag=false;

}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    flag=false;

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You just need to check if the mouse is located over the textfield.

```
final FocusListener fl = new FocusListener () 
{
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
    {
        final JTextField tf= (JTextField) e.getComponent();
        //check for mouse
        if(tf.getMousePosition == null)
        {
            tf.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}
}
```